# How to get between text in special string

Tags: php, substring

My code is here

```
$a = "@ABCD@" ;


echo $a ;  // need print without @ @- ABCD

else 
echo "please enter your text Type in between @ @" ;
```

How is this done in PHP?

Comment: Yes I meant that what you've tried to print ABCD only without @@?

Comment: @Being Sunny i need print only ABCD No Need @@

Comment: search on google for php str_replace()  or trim() function

Comment: simply try like this `echo trim("@ABCD@",'@');`

Comment: @Being Sunny worked.. but I want to check if the value @@ If the answer is 'yes' print ABCD If the answer is 'no', I will do something else.

Comment: @user3783243 How to do it ?

Comment: Voting to close: Your question is unclear, you've rejected the proposed solutions above, because it doesn't "do what you want" (even though it does what you asked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this one way would be:

```
$a = "Testing @ABCD@ this";
$first = (strpos($a, '@') + 1);
$last = strpos(substr($a, $first, (strlen($a) - $first)), '@');
$match = substr($a, $first, $last);
if(!empty($match)) {
    echo 'match';
} else {
    echo 'no match';
}
```

A regex route would be:

```
$a = "Testing @ABCD@ this";
if(preg_match('/@([^@]+)[@]/', $a, $match)) {
  echo 'match'; //$match[0];
} else {
    echo 'No Match';
}
```